# Best questions and answers from the 4th quarter of 2022

Tags: discussion, best-of

As I have mentioned in [previous similar posts](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), some Stack Exchange sites, such as [Literature Stack Exchange](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of), [Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10763/89356), [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) and [Spanish Language SE](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Nominaciones+a+la+mejor+respuesta), have (or had, as the case may be) a tradition of trying to identify the best questions and answers from the last quarter. These are contributions that may be posted on a blog or a Twitter account if the site has one; otherwise they are a nice collection of the best contributions made in a community.

In addition to identifying material that can be used to promote the site elsewhere, such a list of nominations can also be used to highlight high-quality contributions that did not get a lot of votes when they were posted.

So what are the rules?

- Find **great questions and great answers** from the last quarter. There are [273 questions](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2022-09-01..2022-12-31+is%3Aq) and [502 answers](https://french.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2022-09-01..2022-12-31+is%3Aa) to choose from.
- You can nominate multiple posts per answer.
- Some sort of explanation *why* the nominated post is particularly good would be worth adding. This can give future contributors an idea of how to write up good questions or answers.

Comment: Bump!  The community bot just bumped the same question from 2021.  Does an answer needs to be accepted to prevent this year old disconsolate meta thread from running into its predecessor because of the bot?